# Django Datetime not getting saved

Tags: django, datetime

I am trying to create an object of the following model and save it through using code as below.

```
chk_list_for_batch = ChkListForBatch(batch, chk_point, False, datetime.datetime.now())
chk_list_for_batch.save()
```

But, I get the following error

> django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'2019-05-25 11:20:23.240094'
>   value must be either True or False."]

I searched but couldn't find any direction. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Can you share your `ChkListForBatch` model. Normally you construct model objects with *named* parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an object and save it to the database like this:

```
from django.utils import timezone 


chk_list_for_batch = ChkListForBatch.objects.create(batch='batch', 
chk_point='chk_point', some_field=False, creation_time=timezone.now()) 

chk_list_for_batch.save()
```

The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#creating-objects) explain how to create objects in more detail.